# Sending data to and from FormRequest class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to pass data (more precisely an object,`$product`) to and from a FormRequest class, `StoreImageRequest`. After failing validation, the `StoreImageRequest` redirects to the image upload view, which depends on the model `$product` being passed (originally from the controller). As I am not sending any data back to the view, it reads `$product` as `null`.

I need the whole object (`$product`) to pass back to the view. I'm not sure if the model exists in the context of the class, and don't know how I can retrieve it AND pass it on to the redirected view to be used there. Laravel docs point to `protected $redirectRoute = 'route_name';` but give no clue on data. I guess I'm trying to achieve something in the fashion of `return redirect()->route('images.create')->with(['product' => $product]` which works in the controller context.

How can I pass the model again to the view?

**StoreImageRequest:**

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'picture1' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:1000',
        'picture2' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:1000',
        'picture3' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:1000',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'picture1.mimes' => "Los formatos de archivos soportados son .jpg, .bmp, .png",
        'picture1.max' => "Peso de imagen maximo 1MB",

        'picture2.mimes' => "Los formatos de archivos soportados son .jpg, .bmp, .png",
        'picture2.max' => "Peso de imagen maximo 1MB",

        'picture3.mimes' => "Los formatos de archivos soportados son .jpg, .bmp, .png",
        'picture3.max' => "Peso de imagen maximo 1MB",
    ];
}
```

**uploadimage.blade.php**

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <h1>Seleccione las imagenes del producto</h1>
    <p> Producto: {{ $product->name }}</p>
    <p> Id: {{ $product->id }}</p>
    <p> Marca: {{ $product->brand }}</p>
    <form id="image_form" action="{{ route('store.images', $product->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="picture1">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="picture2">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="picture3">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subir imagenes</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... how is this Controller getting this `$product` object?

Comment: Thank you. Method `create` in the ImageController gets it from `$product = session()->get('product');` and sends it to the view via `return view('products.uploadimage', compact('product'));`.

Comment: was that session variable, `product`, flashed? if not it should still be in the session when you are redirected after the validation failure

Comment: Sou you're suggesting to get it the same way (`$product = session()->get('product')`)? if so, how can I pass it back to the view?

Comment: Tried replacing `{{ $product->id }}` with `{{ session()->get('product')->id}}` in the view, still getting `$product` as `null` after failed validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. If the data comes from a Session beforehand, it is possible to retrieve the session in the context of the FormRequest and reflashing it with:

```
    /**
 * Get the session associated with the request.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Session\Store|null
 */
public function getSession()
{
    return $this->session;
    $this->session()->reflash();

}
```

After that the session (and object `$product` within it) will be available for the view to use in the form of

```
{{ session()->get('product') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `getRedirectUrl()` method in your FormRequest class.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Get the URL to redirect to on a validation error.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getRedirectUrl()
    {

        $product_id = $this->route()->parameter('product_id');

        return 'store/' . $product_id . '/images'; // Or whatever your route name is

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry if I didn't clarify enough.  I need the whole model  (`$product`) to pass back to the view. I'm not sure if the model exists in the context of the class, and don't know how I can  retrieve it AND pass it on to the redirected view to be used there. Laravel docs point to protected `$redirectRoute = 'dashboard';"`but give no clue on data. I guess I'm trying to achieve something in the fashion of `return redirect()->route('images.create')->with(['product' => $product]` which works in the controller context.

Comment: Oh right I see - in that case please access the data after form validation failure in your view with `$request->old()` - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#repopulating-forms

Comment: Wouldn't `$request->old()` return the images uploaded before? I'm not trying to repopulate  the form again, I need an object passed down to the view previously by a controller. The object isn't included the `$request`.